# Not able to access host machine from VM

Tags: tcpip, virtual-machines, bridge

I am not able to access the host machine through the VM. And vice-versa.
The networking type of VM is bridged. If I set the type to NAT then I wont be able to access internet. Also I have disabled the firewall on host and the vm.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Datte

Comment: This depends a great deal on both your host and guest operating system. However, it's a server question rather than a programming question, so I'm nudging it over to serverfault.com where it'll get a more targeted response.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the network settings on the VM guest itself.  Run an ipconfig from the command prompt to confirm that it looks correct.  Try pinging the gateway to see if that works.  Make sure that the IP address is in the same subnet as the host server or that the gateway is working properly.  If those don't help solve it, can you provide further information on the settings for the host and guest and Hyper-V network settings?

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> "access the host machine through the
>   VM.  And vice-versa"

do you mean that you cannot access files (drag and drop into/out of the VM or do you mean network connectivity?

If you mean drag and drop out of/into VM check the following settings:
Under the options tab: shared folders.  This will mount a shared folder on both machines, host and VM and allow you to have access to move files into and out of the VM.

If you mean network connectivity then make sure you have your VM tools installed.  Installing the vm tools will also, usually, enable drag and drop functionality.